# Android: Methods for finding matching elements in arrays?

Tags: java, android, comparison

Hi I am stuck in a particular case

I have two arrays, ArrayA[] with 50 items and another ArrayB[] with 10 items.

I want to convert the values of the ArrayB[] (10 items) to be 1 if they match a value in ArrayA[] and 0 if they don't.

I have been trying various techniques for past 5 hours- would be great to get some guidance in what I can do to get this!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, this is what you are looking for:

```
public static void method(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB)
{
    boolean match = false;
    label: for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++)
            if(arrayA[i] == arrayB[j])
            {
                match = true;
                break label;
            }

    int k = (match?1:0);

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++)
        arrayB[i] = k;
}
```

If not, please elaborate!

Comment: That will set all values in arrayB to be either 1 if anything in B is in A, or 0 if nothing in B is in A.  I don't think that's what he wants.

Comment: Thanks for the help- this worked well.  Can you tell me what the purpose of the label: at the beginning of the for statement does?

Comment: @androidbloke `label` is used to break the outter loop from the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
List l = Arrays.asList(arrayA);
for (int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++)
  arrayB[i] = l.contains(arrayB[i]) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work as it seems to put "List l" in to a multidimension array.  when I debug l it shows this- l=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], so as a result all comparisons are failing! and its zeroing out the arrayB